# Convert following String XML into List<string[]>

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, c#-3.0

**I have following string XML**

```
<Abc>
 <a>value1</a>
 <b>value2</b>
 <c />
 <d />
 <x>value3</x>
 <y>value4</y>
 <z />
</Abc>
```

Above XML String Convert to `List<string[]>`
`string[]` have node & value

**Output list Should like this**

[image]

Comment: please check the output image. I want that xml string need to convert to List<string[]>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can easily extract the list of all child elements using `XDocument.Descendants()` and use those to create string arrays, containing the element name and value. Wrap it in a list and you're done:

```
var result = XDocument.Parse(xml)
                      .Descendants()
                      .Select(e => new [] { e.Name.LocalName, e.Value })
                      .ToList();
```

Comment: Code only answers are a no no here. Please add explanation

Comment: Not sure why my answer was singled-out from the ones provided, it's not as if there's more explanation there...

Comment: Getting Error - Data at the root level is invalid. Line 1, position 1.

Comment: `var result = XDocument.Parse(xml)
                      .Descendants()
                      .Select(e => new [] { e.Name.LocalName, e.Value })
                      .ToList();`\n this code working but at 0 index have all the values how to eliminate that

Comment: @CnuVas this was working correctly using the exact XML you've provided. Any chance you could show your input (preferably minimal example showing the problem) and output?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
void Main()
{
    var doc = new XmlDocument();
    doc.LoadXml(str);   
    var result = doc.ChildNodes.OfType<XmlNode>()
    .Select(n=> n.ChildNodes.OfType<XmlNode>().Select(x => $"{x.Name} - {CheckEmpty(x.InnerText)}").ToArray()).ToList();    
}

private string CheckEmpty(string input)
{
    return string.IsNullOrEmpty(input) ? "Empty" : input;
}


string str = @"
<Abc>
 <a>value1</a>
 <b>value2</b>
 <c />
 <d />
 <x>value3</x>
 <y>value4</y>
 <z />
</Abc>
";
```